# How to change the highlight color when the ListView scrolling to the border?

Tags: android, listview

The border displays a default color (that's orange on my Nexus S) while scrolling a ListView to the limit. How to change that color? Any ideas?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign transparent background to your item layout in the list.

Answer (score 0):

set the cache color hint to white: 
setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE).
you change the list items' background color.